# Notice: Undefined index: in C:\wamp\www\somygms\a.php on line 142

Tags: php, mysql

I got an error whenever I run this php code on my local web server:

```
<?php
@ require_once ('C:\wamp\www\Connections\koneksi.php');
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
    header("Location:index.php");
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pasien WHERE noreg = 1122312131";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);

?>

            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="#">
          <table width="804" border="0" id="inputdata" style="border-collapse:collapse">
            <tr>
              <th width="8" rowspan="3" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
              <th width="104" height="50" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" scope="row"><div align="right">Kode Pasien</div></th>
              <td width="250" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><label for="nama"></label>
                <label for="noreg"></label>
                <div align="left">
                <input name="noreg" type="text" id="noreg" size="15" maxlength="13">
                <input type="submit" name="view" id="view"  value="View">       <?php
                @ include_once ('database.php');
                $view = $_POST['view'];
                $noreg = $_POST['noreg'];
                if($view){
                    $_POST[$noreg];
                }
                ?>
```

This is the error:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: view in C:\wamp\www\somygms\a.php on line 139
```

and

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: noreg in C:\wamp\www\somygms\a.php on line 140
```

Thanks for any help, will be appreciated.

-admin

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing those two variables with the array item does not exists.

```
$view = $_POST['view'];
$noreg = $_POST['noreg'];
```

Clearly shows that the `view` and `noreg` are not coming from the POST method. You should check to confirm this. Use `var_dump($_POST);` to see the posted data.

When you are coding, you should make sure that the code you are writing will execute on all cases as much as possible. In your case, initialize the variables before or use isset to check and initialize again.

```
$view = isset($_POST['view']) ? $_POST['view'] : '';
$noreg = isset($_POST['noreg']) ? $_POST['noreg'] : '';
```

---

Now that it is being pointed out.... The page by default will have ***no POST variables ***, so you have filter such cases out

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)) {
    @ include_once ('database.php');
    $view = $_POST['view'];
    $noreg = $_POST['noreg'];
    if($view){
        $_POST[$noreg];
    }
}
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I am not sure If i understand

Comment: The asker is "run[ning] [the] php code", which means they're probably just navigating to it or entering the address in the location bar, which results in a GET request. Hence, an empty `$_POST`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Oh Got it... update in the answer... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its because of you accessing a key in $_POST that doesnt exist. Try the following:

```
$view = (isset($_POST['view']) ) ? $_POST['view'] : '';
$noreg = (isset($_POST['noreg']) ) ? $_POST['noreg'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Call to a member function `fetch()` on a non-object in `C:\wamp\www\chat\chat_vue.php` on line 3